# Ocultar a extensão .html dos arquivos na url usando o .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, url-amigável

Criei algumas páginas `.html` e coloquei on-line. No navegador as extensões dos arquivos ficam visíveis. No entanto quero ocultá-las para deixar as urls mais "amigáveis".

Por exemplo: ao invés de `www.meusite.com/contato.html` quero que apareça somente `www.meusite.com/contato`.

Pesquisando (inclusive nas perguntas similares aqui no site) vi que isso pode ou deve ser feito através do aquivo `.htaccess`. Em muitos tutoriais ou respostas aparece o código abaixo, mas ele não funcionou comigo.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

ps: Não gostaria de transformar minhas páginas `.html` em `.php` porque elas são páginas estáticas.

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Coloquei o seguinte código no arquivo .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)$ /$1.html
```

Fiz o teste com a página "contato" e funcionou. No `index.html` eu alterei a tag `a` que faz o link para a página contato da seguinte forma: De `<a href="contato.html">Contato</a>` para `<a href="contato">Contato</a>`. Ou seja, dentro do site, ao lincar uma página com outra, eu  tirei as extensões dos arquivos. Aparentemente deu certo. **Isso é recomendável?**

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema e resolvi da mesma forma... é isso que vários sites indicam, inclusive este tutorial que achei muito esclarecedor
https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/wiki/comandos-uteis-no-htaccess/

Answer (score 1):

Tenta inserir o código abaixo que também pode ser aproveitado para arquivos que tenham a extensão **.php** apenas terás que substituir **.html** por **.php**:

```
# Reescreve as URLs html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```